# Laravel create/update

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```
        function ()
                 if ($request->ajax())
                {
                    $data = $request->input()
              $organisationGroup = new OrgrpOrganisationGroup;
           $organisationGroup->ORGRPID = $data['Group_Id'];
           $organisationGroup->ORGRPCode = $data['Group_Code'];
           $organisationGroup->ORGRPName = $data['Group_Name'];
           $organisationGroup->MSCONID = $data['Country'];
           $organisationGroup->MSCSTID =$data['State'];
           $organisationGroup->MSCCYID = $data['City'];
           $organisationGroup->MSCURID =$data['Currency'];
                $organisationGroup->save();
```

this is my controller  i am getting form data from blade php through ajax .if i click the button data pass into ajax and then i will come to controller .for update same button if i make update it will come to same controller  function from here its self can i make update ?

Comment: the same question again?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237704/in-laravel-how-to-covert-this-code-create-obeject-into-upsert  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240018/laravel-upsert-create-and-update-with-same-function-in-controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Laravel how to covert this code Create obeject into upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237704/in-laravel-how-to-covert-this-code-create-obeject-into-upsert)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code work for create and for update you must say which data you want update
for update data use this

function (OrgrpOrganisationGroup organisationGroup)
...
...
...
$organisationGroup->save();

Answer (score 0):

If u want to do bolt create/update with only one function, then you have to change it.
**Solutions 1:** Base on your request have an id or not.
Into your controller:

```
public function sendData($id = null, Request $request){  
  if($request->ajax()){  
    if(!$id){  
     OrgrpOrganisationGroup::create($request->all());  
    }  
    else{  
     $orgroOrganisation = OrgrpOrganisationGroup::findOrFail($id);  
     OrgrpOrganisationGroup::update($orgroOrganisation, $request->all());  
    }  
  }  
 }
```

And your route:

```
Route::post('sendData/{id?}',[\App\Http\Controllers\YourController::class,'sendData']);
```

**Solutions 2:**
Your request must be contain id, then your back-end will check id.

```
public function sendData($id, Request $request){  
   if($request->ajax()){  
    $orgroOrganisation = OrgrpOrganisationGroup::findOrFail($id);  
     if(!$orgroOrganisation){  
       OrgrpOrganisationGroup::create($request->all());  
     }  
    else{  
      OrgrpOrganisationGroup::update($orgroOrganisation, $request->all());  
     }  
   }  
}
```

And your route:

```
Route::post('sendData/{id}',[\App\Http\Controllers\YourController::class,'sendData']);
```